# sqlite3 (on qnx): How to get data from a table x mins from the latest time?

Tags: sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database with the following schema:

CREATE TABLE sysTime (time date, source TEXT, destination TEXT, action TEXT, status TEXT, string TEXT, rogue_id TEXT);

[image]

I want to query the db to return only rows inserted in the last x minutes(or hours or days) with respect to the last entered time in the db.

Example: If I want to query the db to return rows inserted in the past 1 day (or 24 hrs), it should only return the last row (i.e 2018-05-09T17:24:25.243 - 24 hours)

I tried using max(time) along with Datetime and it didn't really work:
I found this example online --> **select count(*) from syslog where time >= Datetime('now','-7 days');** and modified it to what I wanted to as below:

**select * from sysTime where time >=Datetime('select max(time) from syslog','-1 day');**

but sqlite3 doesn't return any rows. Tried couple of other sql commands to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Subqueries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subq) are written inside parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM sysTime
WHERE time >= datetime((SELECT max(time) FROM syslog),
                       '-1 day');
```

Comment: Subqueries don't seem to be working inside the datetime. I tried the above query and it returned me 0 rows. But when I appended the actual result of the subquery into the datetime, the main query did return me some rows that I wanted. Eg: **select * from sysTime where time>=datetime('2018-05-10T18:33:55.684','-1 day');** worked!

Comment: SQLite date strings cannot have time zones.